# VS Code, Python ext, autopep8 not formatting

Tags: python, visual-studio, autopep8

When editing in VS Code, "Format Document" doesn't work.  I get an error message:

> Extension 'Python Language Basics' cannot format 'HelloWorld.py'

- Windows 10 OS version: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134
- VS Code version: Code 1.39.2 (6ab5985, 2019-10-15T15:35:18.241Z)
- Python extension is installed, version: 2019.10.44104
- Paths to Python and Python scripts directory, are correct.

I've checked the docs and settings for formatting and autopep8 is specified.
pip works and I've installed autopep8, but it isn't clear to me that this is necessary.  In any case, it doesn't work.
I have de-installed/re-installed Visual Studio Code twice, no effect on the problem

```
import sys, os


print('Hello, World.')


print('This is cool...')

print()
```

Modules should be placed on two lines, extra lines removed.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

De-install Code

De-install Python

Install Code

Install extension

Install Python, don't take quick install, go through custom for all users, and that PATH is updated.

'pip install autopep8' and check the scripts folder, that autopep8 is there and the PATH to the scripts folder is right. Try "autopep8" at a command line to see that it finds it.

Add Python interpreter in Code.

Comment: I reinstalled Code/Python/extension/autopep8 and still have an issue.
autopep8 is included in PATH also

Comment: I reinstalled everything again but also remove VS Code folder completely and remove all PATH items related to Python and VS Code